# How to make request to the MVC API application after the machine is restarted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a MVC API Application and its hosted on my local machine IIS(8.0), In that application I am feeding some other api with the real time data, All works fine until the system is not restarted(or app pool is not restarted/recycled). Is there any way through which I can call my global.asax Application _start event just after the 
system is restarted.

Note: I don't want to use a window service.

Code Snippets of Global.asax :

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
       DadBal dad = new DadBal();
        dad.WriteLogs("App-Started" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), "AppInit");


    }
```

Comment: Isn't your application under IIS? It should start automatically.

Comment: It is, but it will not get started until or unless i make a request on the browser.

Comment: So why you want to start it if no one will make request?

Comment: because its kind of an internal process, with help of sql dependency it raises events to update some other api's.

Comment: try this https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/

Comment: Would it be an option to restructure the application, so that the events are raised by a separate process, so that the MVC application only needs to start when the first request is being made?

Comment: Also, why don't you want to use a service? Because this seems like a perfect use case for a service.

Comment: @Bas 1. No it can not be re-structured as it is existing application 2.It can not be used as a service as this api is being used by the power bi dashboard so calling a web service from a dashboard is not possible.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV : it is for server not for the local iis